# Cauchy Integral Formula with a typo?

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's is another question and solution from the same set as my previous question. This looks like another mistake in the solution to me. I have marked it with the green arrow. This is a typo right? Surely there should be no minus sign here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\hskip 1.2in$ [image: clockwise]

:-)

Comment: Yea I just noticed that now myself. We never did one clockwise example in class so never even thought to look out for it.